# Global variables inside object context

Tags: php

I have an issue, with a class property that I need inside a function in a method In the class. If it is uncleat it looks a bit like that :

```
class Foo {
    public $var;
    public function test() {
        function inside() {
            //Need $this->var here but getting a "not in object context" error
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this way but $var seems null

```
class Foo{
    public $var;
    public function test() {
        $var = $this->var;
        function inside() {
            global $var;
            //but here, $var=null
        }
    }
}
```

So if you have any idea... Thanks
(Here is my code :)

```
public function XML($input) {
    $dt= ($this->datatype) ? $this->datatype : "row";
    function aToXML($data, &$xmlData) {
        global $dt;
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)){
                //here
                $key = $dt.strval(intval($key)+1);
            }
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $subnode = $xmlData->addChild($key);
                aToXML($value, $subnode);
            }
            else {
                $xmlData->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
            }
        }
    }
    if ($this->returnFromArray) {
        $xml=simplexml_load_string("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><data></data>");
        aToXML($input, $xml);
        return $xml->asXML();
    }
    else {
        return ($input) ? "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><success />" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><failure />";
    }

    return $xml->asXML();
}
```

Comment: I would refactor the `function aToXML` to a private or protected method in the class rather than a nested function.

Comment: Yes it might be the best solution

Comment: Nested functions?!? BAD!!! They're not actually nested either, you're really creating an `inside()` function in the global scope, completely independent of the class instance.... and `global` means `global`, not instance related

Answer (score 0):

Please dont. But if you REALLY need an external value try also this.

```
class TheClassThatNeedExternalValue
{
    private $externalValue = null;

    public function injectExternalValue($externalValue)
    {
        $this->externalValue = $externalValue;
    }

    ...
}
```

Global are evil!!!